# Html table with yes/no data?

Tags: html

I need to create an HTML table for a website that has binary yes/no data. I also need a 'yes' to be styled with a tick.

For instance Billy does have a drivers licence, but does not live in London. I need my table to look like this:

[image]

Is this a semantically correct solution?

http://jsfiddle.net/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Has drivers licence?</th>
            <th>Lived in London?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Billy</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Would it still be semantically correct to use ✓ instead of 'Yes'? I need this data to be editable by the CMS so I cant style the tick with a CSS class.

Comment: You can place &nbsp; (space character in html) in the empty tds, it's a usual trick.

Comment: The table looks semantically correct to me. Using a ✓ instead of a yes would be not so good, considering accessibility. Maybe you can hide the `yes` on all devices, just not on screenreaders..

Comment: @jdln Check this post http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/HTML/emptycells.html it seems pretty useful

Comment: @Sebsemillia the issue is that the user has to enter the data and they want as 'yes' state to be styled as a tick.

Comment: @rusben Thanks ill have a look at that link, however currently I dont an issue with empty cells. That is unless its un-semantic to have an empty cell rather than 'No' text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `abbr` tag, to describe the ✓ for screenreaders..

```
<td><abbr title="Yes">✓</abbr></td>
```

Here is another Question concerning this issue:

[How to target a braille / screen-reader via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478173/how-to-target-a-braille-screen-reader-via-css)

Comment: My CMS works by giving the user a normal table with a table heading and the user enters text in the cell. I cant easily add a title attribute or class.

Comment: But you have to tell the CMS to insert the tick symbol, don't you? Then you could just add the extra code. Or do your users have to copy-paste the symbol into the table?

Comment: Yes I was planning on telling my user to copy and paste the tick symbol.

Comment: Well in that case there is no solution to make it automatically accessible in my opinion.